# VBscript Public Property Set/Get equivalent in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to add elements to a Powershell variable with Add-Member.
I have no problem adding static properties with NoteProperty, and methods with ScriptMethod, like that :

```
$variable = New-Object PSObject
$variable | Add-Member NoteProperty Key "Value"
$variable | Add-Member ScriptMethod DoSomething { // code }
```

Now I'm stuck on this :

I want to add a property that has a getter and a setter and does a bunch of things via code block.

The VBScript equivalent would be this :

```
Class MyClass
  Public Property Get Item(name)
    // Code to return the value of Item "name"
  End Property
  Public Property Let Item(name,value)
    // Code to set the value of Item "name" to value "value"
  End Property
End Class
```

Note that the code sections I need to write do more than just set/get the value, they're more complex than that (set other related variables, access external data, etc...).

I failed to find anything this easy in PowerShell and ended up adding instead 2 scriptmethods, GetItem and SetItem.

What would be the best way to implement this get/let functionnality in a member of a PSObject in PowerShell ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `Add-Member` to add a `ParametrizedProperty`, but I failed to find examples for doing so. Documentation is a bit scarce in that regard.

Comment: Yes, parameterizedproperty seemed to be the one I wanted, but it's reserved for another use, as every test I made produced the same error message stating that it's impossible for Add-Member to add a member of type ParameterizedProperty. The error message states that I should choose another MemberTyper.

Comment: parameterized properties are not for end-user usage - they are for the COM adapter mainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `-MemberType ScriptProperty` and use `-Value` and `-SecondValue`:

```
# Make an object with the script property MyProperty
$variable = New-Object PSObject

# “internal” value holder
$variable | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty _MyProperty -Value 42

# get/set methods
$get = {
    Write-Host "Getting..."
    $this._MyProperty
}
$set = {
    Write-Host "Setting..."
    $this._MyProperty = $args[0]
}

# the script property
$variable | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty MyProperty -Value $get -SecondValue $set
```

Test:

```
Write-Host "Original value: $($variable.MyProperty)"
$variable.MyProperty = 123
Write-Host "After assignment: $($variable.MyProperty)"
```

It prints:

```
Getting...
Original value: 42
Setting...
Getting...
After assignment: 123
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to make “protected/private” internal value holders like the note property `_MyProperty` in our example (or whether it is possible at all).

**UPDATE**: Apparently it’s the answer to what more or less the title asks. But the question is in fact about parameterized property, not just get/set methods implemented via script blocks. My attempt to use this type of property (`ParameterizedProperty`) with `Add-Member` has failed, perhaps it is not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks, Roman. Unfortunately, this doesn't allow this kind of access : $variable.MyProperty("property1") = "value1" which is what I'm after.

Comment: Looks like I answered another question. Then @Joey is right, it sounds like you should use `ParametrizedProperty` type.

Comment: And it also looks like `ParametrizedProperty` is not supported. If I try then PS says: “Add-Member : Cannot add a member with type "ParameterizedProperty". Specify a different type for the MemberTypes parameter.” Thus, perhaps your `GetItem`/`SetItem` script methods is a way to go.

Comment: Answer will do. I guess it's indeed not feasible in pure Powershell as parameterizedproperty members cannot be created via add-member.